# Getting Errors When Using User Input to Pull Data in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, datetime, input

I am trying out code that uses input from the user to pull data in that date range. My date is the 23rd column (yes, I know the index starts at 0) and is formatted in excel like so: 1/1/2007

Here is the code:

```
import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from_raw = raw_input('\nEnter FROM Date (e.g. 2013-11-29) : ')
    from_date = datetime.date(*map(int, from_raw.split('-')))
    print 'From date: = ' + str(from_date)
    to_raw = raw_input('\nEnter TO Date (e.g. 2013-11-30) : ')
    to_date = datetime.date(*map(int, to_raw.split('-')))

    in_file = './MyFileTest.csv'
    for line in in_file:
        fields = line.split(',')
        found_date = datetime.date(*map(int, fields[23].split(' ')[23].split('-')))
        if from_date <= found_date <= to_date:
            print line

    in_file.close()
```

However, I am getting a IndexError: list index out of range for my code. If I change 23 to 0, I instead get the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'

Does anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?

The 23rd column (Column index X in Excel) looks like this:

```
receiveddate
1/1/2007
1/1/2007
1/1/2007
1/2/2007
1/2/2007
1/2/2007
1/2/2007
1/2/2007
1/2/2007
1/2/2007
12/28/2006
12/29/2006
12/29/2006
1/2/2007
```

I chanced some of the split commands to split('/') to see if that would help but since it is claiming that the list index out of range, this aspect of the code doesn't matter yet.

Comment: What is in the line that is causing the error?  What is in `fields`? (This is assuming it is the line computing `found_date` is the one causing the error; you don't really say.)

Comment: @ScottHunter  Sorry, you are right, the line causing the error is found_date. I thought fields was using line.split(',') from the line above, no?

Comment: Yes, that's how `fields` gets computed, but what *value* is going in there?  Knowing that will help in determining what to *do* with it (remember, you haven't shown anything of what is in your csv file).

Comment: @ScottHunter I may be a bit confused. I thought that I was giving fields the 23rd column of my csv, which is a column of dates formatted this way: 1/2/2007.

Comment: What is actually in the 23rd column of the line that of the csv that is causing the error?

Comment: @ScottHunter I added a sample copy paste of what the 23rd column looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is a real unedited copy-paste, here's your problem :

```
fields[23].split(' ')[23].split('-')
```

Which decomposed gives us something like:

```
 what = fields[23].split(' ')
 what = what[23].split('-')
```

So the index error is on the `ẁhat[23].split()` part obviously.

Comment: So the index error is happening in the second part, but what do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You know about the [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method? With this you must not convert your data:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('2015-06-17', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2015, 6, 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the other answers:

- `fields[23]` is your date, in the form *M*`/`*D*`/`*Y*
- So `fields[23].split("/")` will give you a list of the individual components, which you can use as you originally did to make a date (but they're in the wrong order)
- Instead, you should use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to parse `fields[23]` into a date, using the format `"%m/%d/%Y"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. found_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(fields[23], "%m/%d/%Y" )

IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: Since you seem reticent to share just what fields contains, you're on your own on that one, but if it is has 23 columns, and your date is in the last one, then either fields[22] or fields[-1] should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that I wasn't actually reading my file.